# logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics() does not work in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I've updated my project from .net core 2.1 to 2.2 and then `logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()` in `Program.cs` no longer works.

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            })

            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

> 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics' and no accessible extension method 'AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Referring to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2),

> If targeting .NET Framework or referencing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage, add the provider package to the project. Invoke AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics on an ILoggerFactory instance:

So the way might be slightly different from the previous one. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: might be a silly question.. have you added the `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` statement?

Comment: Yes I have the statement. It was working with .net 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: also in the linked document it says, `If targeting .NET Core, note the following points:

Don't explicitly call AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics.`

Comment: I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` as well, that's why I referred to the statement in the document.

Comment: that talks abt invoking AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics on an ILoggerFactory instance. here you have ILoggingBuilder. And as you can see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.azureappservicesloggerfactoryextensions.addazurewebappdiagnostics?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_AzureAppServicesLoggerFactoryExtensions_AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggerFactory_), that method is set as Obsolete with a comment `will be removed in a future version.The alternative is AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(this ILoggingBuilder builder)`

Comment: I understand. So can I just comment out the function call and use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` instead?

Comment: could you check if logs are coming without the call (comment AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics)?

Comment: Umm oddly the logs still come without the function call... How does the app output them? Anyway I think now I can just comment it out and get to 2.2. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#logging-in-azure) is a bit tricky but if read carefully it become clear that following steps should be undertaken (for **NET Core**):

1. `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` should be installed
2. There is NO need to call `logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();`
3. Logging can be configured using following code

   ```
   // file startup.cs
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;

   public class Startup
   {
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           //...
           services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureLogging"));
       } 
   }
   ```

   File `appsettings.json` should contain

   ```
   "AzureLogging": {
        "FileName" : "azure-diagnostics-",
        "FileSizeLimit": 50024,
        "RetainedFileCountLimit": 5
   }
   ```
4. Logging should be turned on on Azure Portal. After enabling, Azure Portal may ask for installing addon. Message requiring to install addon will appear on logging config page.

[image]

5. Call `logger.LogWarning ("message");` in your code to write to log file. If you use `LogWarning` be sure to set Level to Warning or more detailed (Info or Debug)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me take a look at my code when I have a time.

Comment: Is there any way to test it locally? for the logs to be saved locally?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that stated you didn't need to call `logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();`. Is this based on something you've read or just from experience? The docs code sample you've linked to do include this code, so I think it's probably safer to make the call.

Comment: @ajbeaven, Azure gives you the option to install the extension automatically if you don't want to make code changes. If you want to be explicit then you can install the NuGet manually and call `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()`. See: https://mderriey.com/2020/08/08/a-look-at-the-aspnet-core-logging-provider-for-app-service/#how-to-enable-it

Comment: @CrazyTim awesome, good find!

Comment: Yeah that's some strange secret magic that you *do* have to hook up file logging, and using that particular object, and you *don't* actually have to call AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics. There's an example that shows the file logging being hooked up but no clear implication that that's necessary (on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#azure-app-service). I would've guessed it just had trace output and that was essentially "live" by calling the extension method.