# Azure Log Stream does not work at all for my Blazor .net core 3.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I can't manage to run Azure LogStream for my Blazor app.

I think I did everything

1. I installed extension NuGet

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="3.1.4" />
```

2. I added providers

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                }) 
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

3. I installed server extension

[image: screen]

4. I enabled logs

[image: screen2]

5. And I got nothing
   [image: screen3]

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930748/logging-addazurewebappdiagnostics-does-not-work-in-net-core-2-2 ?

Comment: that's new. will try, thx!

Comment: Could you solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: I solved it using this. Maybe it's helpful for you @xakz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749481/i-cannot-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream